# interpolating option volatility in R

Tags: r, finance, quantmod, volatility

I have a bunch of deltas and option implied vols at those deltas. I would like to interpolate them in R.  I was thinking of simply doing the following:

```
#first convert everything to moneyness type measure
sample_delta = c(seq(-.5, -.05, by=.05), seq(.05, .55, by=.05))
sample_vols = runif(n = length(sample_delta)) #some made up vols
d1 = ifelse(sample_delta <0, qnorm(sample_delta +1), qnorm(sample_delta ))
s = spline(d1, sample_vols)
```

The issue is that I have to go back and forth converting between `d1` and `delta` when at the end of the day I just want things to be in standardized delta space.  Does R have any packages to do this? FOr example `quantmod` or something of the sort.

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear (what do you mean by "I have to go back and forth between d1 and delta"?).  Also, it might be better suited to http://quant.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I just meant that I can't think of a good way to interpolate in delta space because you want to paste the ATM calls with ATM puts but if delta is on the x-axis they are on opposite ends.